Distribute power from one battery to multiple devices
I have a battery, Li-po 3300mAh 22.2V 60C. Then, I have a system (main system, so to speak) which consist of STM32MP1 MPU (operating voltage [1.71, 3.6], typ. 3.3), STA8135GA GNSS IC (operating voltage [1.71, 3.6], typ. 3.3), and 12 motors (4 of them are 12V brushed DC motors). All these components on that system, works in certain amount (range) of voltage, right? The question is, how can I create a system - above the main system - to distribute power correctly from that battery to all the component on the main system?
Maybe I could name it the "power distribution system". How would that be?
I'm guessing it's all about DC-DC converters, voltage regulators thingy, am I right? Hence, I'm probably creating a "power supply unit" I should say. I'm still confused about the distribution workflow. Am I going to need just 1 DC-DC converter, then it would forward the desired amount of voltage into "terminals/hubs/ports"? Or am I going to need more than 1 of it?
Regarding motors, I would need an ESC, which will be designed with the MPU.

What kind of "system" are you designing? A control panel, a single circuit board, a collection of circuit boards, something else?

A collection of circuit boards. GNSS IC I talked about is built with Cortex M7. Whereas the MPU is built with Cortex A7 and M4. So far, I should create 2 boards. @davide said I should use an ESC for grouped DC motors, which I will group them in 3, there I would need 3 ESCs. Finally, I should create 3 boards in total.


All these components on that system, works in certain amount (range) of voltage, right?

Right.

how can I create a system - above the main system - to distribute power correctly


Do not power the motors directly. Power them through the appropriate motor driver (e.g., an ESC for a brushed DC motor)
Group all the loads based on their desired operating voltages (e.g., 12 V, 5 V)
Convert the battery voltage to those voltages with DC-DC converters
Connect all the 12 V devices together in parallel and to the output of the 12 V DC-DC converter, all the 5 V devices to the output of the 5 V DC-DC converter, etc. All the devices share a common ground.


simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
